# Microsoft Word - on the web version - how do you turn on normal page visibility instead of displaying only page breaks

Tags: microsoft-word

I've checked out multiple questions and answers, as well as many other forums etc. but I couldn't find the answer.

How do you display normal pages with empty space, instead of the horizontal line/rule indicating a page break?

I know about the Show White Space Between Pages, setting but can't find it in the web version of Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The web version is a reduced-function-set of the desktop application.* See [Differences between using Word in the browser and the desktop application](https://support.office.com/client/Differences-between-using-a-document-in-the-browser-and-in-Word-3E863CE3-E82C-4211-8F97-5B33C36C55F8).

### Change to Reading View

This gives you something that looks very much like Print View in the desktop application, but you can't edit the document in this view. It will also show headers and footers.